# Kuman 3,5 inch RPI display white screen with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3

I just recently bought a Raspberry pi 3 and a Kuman 3.5 inch RPI Display.
When I put the included micro SD card with the boot files into the pi, it shows a white screen and when I wait some time for it to boot up, it does not, the white screens remains until I shut off the pi. NEED HELP!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the drivers [here](https://mega.nz/#F!DRUwEDgI!Ug1aoighYUN0uLdEhTC-sA).

1.You need to install the /driver/LCD-show-160701.tar.gz file.

2.Go to the terminal where you installed this file.

3.Do:

```
sudo tar zxvf LCD-show-160701.tar.gz
cd LCD-show/
sudo ./LCD35-show
```

4.It's done!

PS: If you want to go back to the HDMI, go to the previous folder and do:

```
sudo ./LCD-hdmi
```